# Password validation always fails

Tags: php, validation, yii, passwords

I'm making a log in in system and the password validation fails every time, simply saying it's an incorrect password.  The section with the comment slashes(//) is the part that is causing the trouble, I am also using the YII framework.

```
    $users= Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('Email'=>$this->Email));

    if($users===null) {
       $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID; 
    }
    //else if($users->validatePassword($this->Password)) {
    //   $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    // echo 'failed here 2';
    // }
    else {           
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
        $this->_id = $users->UserID;
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}

public function getId() {
    return $this->_id;
}
```

and here is the validate password function

```
public function validatePassword($password)
{
  return $this->Password = hash('sha256',$this->Password);
}
```

Comment: `=` is an assignment. `==` is comparison

Comment: (also: you say: if it is valid, then error? i'd say if it isn't valid, then error. Test your code. Echo/var_dump/debug your variables. step trough everything to stop these kinds of minor bugs.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with my = signs

Comment: think what your validate function should do. Should it a. assign a hash to the property "Password", or b. check if that hash is equal to the current value of the property "Password". If it is a, then your functionname is incorrect, if it s b then your code is incorrect.

Comment: It's alright now, i re wrote it from scratch and it works

Comment: @arenthor - The SHA* hash functions are not appropriate to hash passwords (especially unsalted), because they are ways too fast. Instead use a slow hash function like BCrypt with a cost factor, see [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this is just for testing purposes, if product gets launched security would be beefed up before release, using bycrypt or similar along with a salt

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are a couple of problems with this function

First this statement is a test, it should test that $this->Password is equal to the password you pass in as a parameter.

1. you dont actually use the parameter in the test
2. its not a test as you use `=` and not `==`

So it should be coded as

```
public function validatePassword($password)
{
  return $this->Password == hash('sha256',$password);
}
```

As this method exists in the users object `$this->Password` is whatever has been loaded to the `$users->Password` property ( which I assume you have already loaded from the database ) and you test that it is equal to the hash of the plain-text password that was passed to the script from the form.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

*Re your comment: That has stopped the invalid password error, however it's just accepting any old password now*

Well now you need to look at the code that tests the result of calling the fixed function.

Your code:

```
else if($users->validatePassword($this->Password)) {
   $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
   echo 'failed here 2';
}
```

Fixed version:

```
else if( ! $users->validatePassword($this->Password)) {
   $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
   echo 'failed here 2';
}
```

SECOND ADDITIONAL INFO:

You need to add some debug code to see what data you are actually comparing try this :-

```
    $users= Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('Email'=>$this->Email));

    echo '<pre>users object ' . print_r($users,true) . '</pre>';
    echo 'The password we are testing = ' . $this->Password . '<br>';

    if($users===null) {
       $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID; 
    }
    else if( ! $users->validatePassword($this->Password)) {
       $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
       echo 'failed here 2';
    }
    else {           
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
        $this->_id = $users->UserID;
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}
```

Comment: That has stopped the invalid password error, however it's just accepting any old password now

Comment: Again auto failure of all passwords, feels like im stuck on a roundabout

Comment: I assume you did hash the password with the same algorithm when you stored them on the database as you are using in the `validatePassword($password)` method??

Comment: Actually come to think of it this line `return !$this->errorCode;` probably should be `return $this->errorCode;`

Comment: yea, turns out though, that if i use a single = it approves every password and if i sue == it fails them all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58687/discussion-between-arenthor-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: Look `$this->Password = hash('sha256',$password);` says set `$this->Password` equal to the result of this funtion `hash('sha256',$password)` but with a function called `validatePassword($password)` you should be testing IF `$this->Password ` IS EQUAL TO the result of this function call `hash('sha256',$password)`